# Running Meteor.js in production without combining and minifying JS files

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to run Meteor in production and view the JavaScript files separately in the console similar to development? I am doing some debugging that will be much easier in production if it is possible. Perhaps there is a default minification package that can be removed during testing and development?

Comment: i just saw how to do this, i think. i'll come back here if i recall where i saw it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add commandline parameter --debug to your meteor deploy or meteor bundle command.

Comment: Any idea how I might achieve this with [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up)?

Comment: In the mup config you can specify a custom meteor binary https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/blob/master/README.md Try setting that to meteor --debug

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.